# Should a question be marked as duplicate even if it would help later users?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The question ([How to write a good resignation letter when quitting under poor circumstances?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/82177/how-to-write-a-good-resignation-letter-when-quitting-under-poor-circumstances)) has been viewed 3844 times in 2 days and received 29 upvotes, but marked as duplicate. This must be because the earlier answers were not satisfying or the situation was different.

Also, my question ([Is it fair to expect increment in pay for changing location?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/82228/is-it-fair-to-expect-increment-in-pay-for-changing-location)) is different from the question marked duplicate ([Does my geographic location matter when requesting a salary?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/29/3192)) because the user in that question was not already an employee of the company, so the answers have got to be different.

Answers should either be not allowed, or the duplicate marking should be taken off such questions. The situation for such questions is mostly different, but marking them as duplicate leads to same answers in all situations. Why are such questions marked duplicate even if they are contributing much to SE?

Comment: If it's really a duplicate, then the original should be equally useful to later users.

Comment: By the way, I suggest you avoid using "Is it right" and "is it fair" so often. It comes across as preaching. It almost sounds like rather than trying to understand how this site works, you are expecting us to defend it to conform to your high standards.

Comment: @MaskedMan I'll take care of it.But I say that because I'm yet not that experienced as user so somethings might have been misinterpreted by me.

Comment: +1 what Joe said.

Comment: "*This must be because the earlier answers were not satisfying or the situation was different.*". No, it's because it hit HNQ and none of the regulars realised that it's pretty much an exact duplicate of a previous question. Dupe votes after the question hits HNQ are annoying and don't always succeed but just because the question got exposure doesn't mean that it's not a dupe. As for your final question: look into the reason we have duplicate votes. Question fragmentation is entirely counter to SE's philosophy and hence do *not* contribute to the site.

Comment: your problem current is that you are asking if it is fair.  Change your question to ask how to ask for an increase in pay to offset cost of living increases due to relocation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see the problem.

If answers to the other question do not solve your problem, edit your question explaining why, and ask to reopen it. (Your question is not closed as of now, though.) You could also link to the question in your original description, so that people know you have already searched for existing questions which do not work for you.

For the other question, OP already got useful answers before the question was closed as a duplicate. In addition, by linking to other (duplicate) questions, he also got more answers, which he may not have searched for earlier.

Linking the question as duplicate is also useful for future users, who come here via search engines. People may enter different phrases to describe the same issue in search engines, and having various linked questions helps them find their answer sooner.

Answer (score 2):

On the first case :

The answer is the same and the question are really near "what should i say in resignation letter -> Only that you're leaving, nothing else". So whatever the people that upvoted, the question in itself has add no value to the site.

The other is a bit trickier, althought the question seems really different, the arguments to answer both of them are the same : managers are aware that cost of living is not the same anywhere and so adjust the salary.

This quote from the answer is all what you need as an answer to your question :

> Your responsibility
>
> That being said, the recruiter is not going to just give away money
>   that they don't feel they need to, as with any negotiation.
>
> They will be prepared to have the discussion — if you say you
>   currently make $40K in a cheaper area, they'll be prepared to hear
>   that you need a significant "cost of living increase" — but you must
>   be prepared to ask and hold up your end of the negotation with real
>   numbers.

Answer (score 1):

A few things of note.

Duplicate questions are treated differently from other close reasons.  The question no longer accepts new answers, but it is linked to the other questions most users will find useful when searching.  The question will remain on the site where other types of closed questions will be pruned periodically.

When updating a question to clear up a misconception that the question is a duplicate, you must explain why the question is not a duplicate, and why the existing answers do not work or apply.  This is probably best done by providing a change to the question you are asking.  In this case I would change that question to: **How do I ask for an increase in pay to offset cost of living increases due to relocation**  This clears up the problem that comes from the questions being asked seeming to be the same.